# Getting tied values from arraylist

Tags: java

An updated version with original condition.

A method called getMost that takes a single integer parameter and returns
an ArrayList of Personality objects. You may assume that the
parameter’s value will be greater-than or equal-to 0 but it might be greater
than the number of items in the Competition object’s list.
This method must return an ArrayList containing the Personality
objects of the Competition with the most votes. The ArrayList returned
must be a different one from the one in the Competition object but the
Personality objects will be the same ones. For instance, if the parameter is
3 then the method must create a new ArrayList, store within it the three
Personality objects that have the highest number of votes, and return that
list.

When writing this method you should consider the following special cases:
• If the parameter’s value is greater-than or equal-to the number of personalities
in the list then all of the personalities will be returned.
• There might be a tie for votes, which could mean that the returned list might
contain more objects than the parameter value. For instance, if the top 3 are
required and the top five personalities have 100, 98, 50, 50 and 42 votes, then
four personalities must be returned. On the other hand, if the top 3 are
required and the top five have 100, 100, 98, 50, 50 and 42 votes then exactly
three would be returned.

code deleted>>

Comment: can you shar what have you done so far?

Comment: Please show us the code you've written so far and where exactely are you stuck. Otherwise this is just another of "please do my homework for me" questions.

Comment: This is a 'do my homework' question...

Comment: I have updated my original question. And yes, it is homework question, but Im not piggy back  riding, I really do my best. Im just very new into coding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're allowed to use streams. but this code fragment does what you ask: (Numbers is your List with numbers)

```
private static long getNumber(int number) {
    if (number < 1 || number >= numbers.size()) return number;
    int numberFromList = numbers.get(number - 1);
    return (number + numbers.stream().filter(n -> n == numberFromList).count()) - 1;
}
```

Next time please add some code you've already tried.

Comment: wel this would work for int numbers only, as I understand. But my arraylist has an objects with different values, amount of vote, name, and so on.